# Developing both Rails Web App and Android App that shares only one Database

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-connection

I'm a 3rd year BSIT student who wants to pursue a career of Web Development in the near future. We decided for our thesis to make a Web App about a certain topic using Ruby on Rails since it's the tool that we used during our WebDev class. I've had several experiences and accomplished projects using RoR thanks to the help of this site.

Our Adviser suddenly suggested us to make an Android version of the app for the customer's side to utilize it's portability. what we would like to happen is the Customers can input and retrieve data through that android app from a database, on the other hand, the admin can also do the same using a Desktop Web App utilizing also the the same database used by the customers.

Is there any other recommendations of lightweight development and database tools that can help us make the desired Web App beside Android Studio and Eclipse? Much better if it can support Rails or Ruby.

*Note: Also, we're planning to include a GPS feature where you can locate certain shops using the said android app*

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is an API. You have a Rails app, now you have to expose API endpoints from your Rails App which your Android App can access and send requests to.

I don't know if you learned about APIs yet but in short, you set up new links that retrieve information from the parameters and respond using either JSON or XML. Your android app will for example have a login form:

```
Name = john
Password = anything
```

When they submit the form, you take the name and password and send it using an HTTP request from Android to your Rails App.

```
#stupid example but this is how the link would somehow look like
http://www.your-site.com/api/login?name=john&password=anything
```

Your rails app should be setup to receive request via an API controller:

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController
  def login
   #authenticate user
   #respond with json
  end
end
```

Your Android app receives a JSON response from Rails, usually a status code telling Android that the authentication was successful or failed and then you have access to your Web App using Android but nothing is secure and you will have to setup tokens for each request, etc because API's don't have sessions like a browser. But since you are talking about a school project and not a production app maybe you can ignore the security part.

Read this blog post on how to build an API:

https://labs.kollegorna.se/blog/2015/04/build-an-api-now/